# How to switch the Apple ID when update the mac's softs?

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore

When I update the softs of my Mac, there only can use the previous AppleID, but I want to switch other Apple ID, how can I do that? I can not click the Apple ID textfield.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Menu Bar select Store > Sign Out. Now select Store > Sign In...